# Include an external file in a Windows Service Deployment using sc.exe

Tags: configuration, windows-service

I'm trying to deploy a windows service using a command like this:

```
sc create MyApp binpath="C:\Path\service.exe"
```

However, my service uses an external config file for some settings.  Is there a way to force an inclusion of the config file in the deployment?

Comment: some application uses it is own command to create windows services for example mysql use mysqld.exe what is the application you are trying to use.

Comment: Assuming that you're talking about instructing the service where to find its config file, there's no way to answer that without more information about the service.  Have you checked the relevant documentation?  Or is this a service you've written yourself?

Comment: I wrote it myself.  I'm sort of under the impression that there might be an SC switch to include an external file.  Obviously, I could simply hard code the path to the config file to somewhere, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having one.